# Why PHP Force Download script does not work if I include a space (%20) inside the URL?

Tags: php, readfile

I am using a PHP force download script as following:-

```
$file_Name = $_GET['name'];
$file_Url = $_GET['file'];
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description:     File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_Name");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file_Url);
exit;
```

**If URL of my link is like:-** */image.php?name=Germany.png&file=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fstaticmap%3Fcenter%3D**Germany**%26zoom%3D15%26size%3D240x320%26maptype%3Droadmap%26mobile%3Dtrue%26sensor%3Dfalse*, so it is working without any trouble!

And if I include a space (%20) inside the URL and try to visit it, browsers are showing me "Download Failed"!

**Example URL:-**  */image.php?name=Image.png&file=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fstaticmap%3Fcenter%3D**River%20Annan**%26zoom%3D15%26size%3D240x320%26maptype%3Droadmap%26mobile%3Dtrue%26sensor%3Dfalse*

So, why is this happening? What's going wrong with it?

Comment: While the actual question being asked of why is a mystery to me atm, I would like to point out that this script is very dangerous. If someone were to type in "config.php" in the file and you had your configuration file like that. It would display all your confidential information. You should filter your input before using it. `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'file', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace space with `-` then try to read url

```
$file_Name = $_GET['name'];
$file_Url = $_GET['file'];
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description:     File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_Name");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo readfile(str_replace(" ","-",$file_Url));
exit;
```

Comment: Is `exit;` unnecessary? You've not included it!

Comment: I've used `echo readfile(str_replace(" ","%20",$file_Url)); exit;` instead! But both works!

Answer (score 1):

That happens, because accordingly to php docs, "The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded.", so %20 is replaced by space.
The following code should work:

```
readfile(urlencode($file_Url));
```

+1 for general unsafety of the code

Comment: this will  also encode `/`and other content which will nit necessary. try your solution with OP example. It will ended up with error

Comment: Ok, so more work is needed, first split the path by "/", then encode everything except domain and join again